# SQLite in Android: deleting rows

Tags: android, sqlite

My android application uses an sqlite database and during first run it deletes some rows. The next time it runs it tries to do the same , but because the rows were previously deleted it fails. I use SQLite database browser to inspect the database, after first run (when the rows are deleted) and I observe that the rows that no longer should exist are still in the database, even if ehwn running the app again those rows are no longer visible !    What is the cause for this behavior ?

Comment: So, the rows are deleted only the second time or the rows are not deleted at all ?

Comment: we would need some more info, some code probably , right now its too vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have overcome this by throwing everything into a Cursor and then checking the size of the Cursor object using its getCount() method; if it comes out as zero, then I branch off and stop attempting any DB actions other than creating rows/tables.